# python Scrapy CrawlSpider: Rule doesn't apply after logged in, only crawled the first page

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm a C/C++ programmer with limited python experience in making plot and text processing. I'm currently working on a personal data analysis project and I'm using Scrapy to crawl all the threads and user info in a forum.

I've put together an initial code aiming to login at first, then start from the indexing page of a subforum, doing the following thing:

1) extract all the thread link which contains "topic"

2) save the page in a file for now (will extract item info once the whole process works)

3) find next page link which has tag class=next, go to next page and repeat 1) and 2)

I know for each thread, I still need to go through all the pages contain all the reply posts, but I plan to do it once I get my current code work correct.

However, my current code will only extract all the threads in the starting url, and then stops. I've searched several hours and didn't find any solution for this. So I ask my question here and hope someone with experience with Scrapy can help me out here. If you guys want any other info such as the output please let me know. Thanks!

Regarding Paul's reply, I updated my code, there's something wrong with my link extractor, I will need to fix it. Other than that, the Rule now works fine. Thanks to Paul's help again.

Here's my current spider code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class ZhuaSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'zhuaspider'
    allowed_domains = ['depressionforums.org']
    login_page = 'http://www.domain.com/forums/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login'
    start_urls = ['http://www.depressionforums.org/forums/forum/12-depression-central/']

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="next"]'), unique=True),
                           callback='parse_links',
                           follow=True),
            )

    def start_requests(self):
        """called before crawling starts. Try to login"""
        yield Request(
                url=self.login_page,
                callback=self.login,
                dont_filter=True)

    def login(self, response):
        """Generate a login request."""
        return FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'ips_username': 'myuid', 'ips_password': 'mypwd'},
                callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
        """Check the response returned by a login request to see if we are successfully logged in."""
        if "Username or password incorrect" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed.")
        else:
            self.log("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!")
            # Now the crawling can begin.
            for url in self.start_urls:
                # explicitly ask Scrapy to run the responses through rules
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_links(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        links = hxs.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "topic")]')
        for link in links:
            title = ''.join(link.xpath('./@title').extract())
            url = ''.join(link.xpath('./@href').extract())
            meta={'title':title,}
            yield Request(url, callback = self.parse_posts, meta=meta,)

    #If I add this line it will only crawl the starting url,
    #otherwise it still won't apply the rule and crawls nothing.
    parse_start_url = parse_links

    def parse_posts(self, response):
        filename = 'download/'+ response.url.split("/")[-2]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make use of `CrawlSpider`'s `Rules`, you need your `Requests` to be processed by the internal `parse()` method.

You can do that by explicitly setting `callback=self.parse` or not setting a callback.

```
start_urls = ['http://www.depressionforums.org/forums/forum/12-depression-central/']

rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="next"]'), unique=True),
                           callback='parse_links',
                           follow=True),
)

...

def check_login_response(self, response):
    """Check the response returned by a login request to see if we are successfully logged in."""
    if "Username or password incorrect" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed.")
    else:
        self.log("Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!")
        # Now the crawling can begin.
        for url in self.start_urls:
            # explicitly ask Scrapy to run the responses through rules
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Then, with that alone you should see pages for links in `//li[@class="next"]` sections being crawled and parsed using `parse_links()`... expect the start_urls themselves.

To go through `parse_links` for start_urls, you have to define a special [`parse_start_url`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.parse_start_url) attribute.

You can do this:

```
def parse_links(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    links = hxs.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "topic")]')
    for link in links:
        title = ''.join(link.xpath('./@title').extract())
        url = ''.join(link.xpath('./@href').extract())
        meta={'title':title,}
        yield Request(url, callback = self.parse_posts, meta=meta,)

parse_start_url = parse_links
```

Comment: Thanks Paul! I tried your method, but it won't apply the rules. After I change the callback in check_login_response function to self.parse, it doesn't crawl anything. It I add parse_start_url = parse_links then it will crawl the starting url. Do you know why this happens? Thanks again for your timely answer.

Comment: I had to run it myself to see the problem: you need to define your rules in a `rules` attribute as a tuple. See edited code

Comment: Thanks Paul, I defined the rules tuple and it works. Well now I know there's error in my link extractor because it doesn't extract correct links, but I think I will fix that myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, it help me a lot.